# Record screen (screencast) using HTML5, e.g. getUserMedia or something?

Tags: browser, html5-video, screen-capture

Is there some HTML5 API that can help me record the screen (screencast)? I know about recording webcams etc, but I need the screen it self. It would help even more if this API was actually implemented in some cross-platform browser.

Answer (score 2):

Screen capture is available as an experimental feature in Chrome, and you must enable it in your browser settings (chrome://flags/#enable-usermedia-screen-capture). Also, it seems to only work on an https connection.

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'screen'
        // maxWidth: 640,
        // maxHeight: 480
      }
    }
  },
  function (stream) {
    //success! Now set up the video
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.autoplay = true;
    //you can choose to display the video here or not.
  },
  function () {
    //failure. browser is unable or permission denied
  }
);
```

Once you have the video set up, it is possible to record it. There is a standard drafted for media recording, but it's not implemented in any browsers yet. However, it is still possible. Refer to this [demo and sample code](http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia) for a workaround.

Unfortunately, for now, this solution is available for Chrome only.

Comment: The solution you describe records what comes from the camera, it’s not a screencast as the OP requested.

Comment: That's because this answer is a year old, and the experimental feature has been removed. You now need a browser extension to make it work. details here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing

Answer (score 0):

Screen capture is possible via the MediaRecorder API, and recording from a hidden canvas.

Here's [an example](https://gist.github.com/veltman/ff864215009174bc5d164ec3533125c2)