# HTML5 - Able to do desktop screen cast? Assume not....Ideas?

Tags: html

I'm getting ready to start an HTML5 web app and I would love it to allow my users to be able to share their desktop to an audience.

Imagine I have a ppt, I want to broadcast my powerpoint presentation to 3 to 5 viewers, in remote locations. I am navigating the powerpoint slides with audio, and they are watching it.

How can I make this work?

1) I guess I can manually upload my powerpoint deck to the HTML5 client in my browser, and convert that into some format, send it to the server and then to the clients and navigate it, outside of powerpoint. But then I can't support excel, or whatever else is on my desktop.

2) Do I need a client application that somehow streams / pushes my desktop viewport into the browser? Is this even possible?

3) Other methods / ideas?

I understand why security restrictions would prevent this from happening in the open web. But imagine an intranet, business use case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record screen (screencast) using HTML5, e.g. getUserMedia or something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440120/record-screen-screencast-using-html5-e-g-getusermedia-or-something)

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/