# best screencasting api for web browser

Tags: web, screencast

I'm trying to add screencasting ability to my website. is there any API for screencasting on browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking here:
https://github.com/TechSmith/screencast-developer-docs/blob/master/sections/getting_started.md

"In summary:

One time, the application developer requests and obtains an API key and API secret used to uniquely identify that application.
One or more times, the application requests and obtains an AuthCode to access content on behalf of a user who has provided the application with his or her credentials.
Most times, the application includes the AuthCode with calls to access user content.
Every time, the application signs calls made to the server with a call signature."

Comment: also check this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440120/record-screen-screencast-using-html5-e-g-getusermedia-or-something